# How to solve equations with jump condition?

Tags: classical-mechanics, boundary-conditions, continuum-mechanics

Consider two regions $\Omega_1, \Omega_2$ that are separated with a surface $\Sigma$. In Region $\Omega_i$ one has the wave equation

$$\partial_t^2 u - c_i^2 \partial_x^2 u = 0,c_i = \sqrt{\frac{E_i}{\rho_i}}$$

with Initial conditions $\partial_tu(x,t=0)=v_0$ in $\Omega_1$ and $\partial_tu(x,t=0)=0$ in $\Omega_2$. The jump conditions on $\Sigma$ are:

$$[|E\partial_xu|] = 0~ ?$$

If two objects collide, which are the jump conditions? I still can't handle jump conditions. And how to solve equations with jump conditions?

My solution Ansatz:

$u = \psi_{1-}(x-c_1t)+\psi_{1+}(x+c_1t)$ for Region 1

$u = \psi_{2-}(x-c_2t)+\psi_{2+}(x+c_2t)$ for Region 2

The Goal is: Compute the stresses that act in $\Omega_1$ after Impact. Why stresses are greater if $\Omega_2$ is a tough material like Stone or metal than if $\Omega_2$ is a soft material?